# Missing ; before 'type' error

Tags: c, compiler-construction

This is part of my code, do you know what causes this missing ; before 'type' error? It disappears when I delete sort(arr, size) in the main() function...

```
#include <stdio.h>

    void sort(int*, int);

    int main() {
        int arr[] = {5, 1, 3, 0, 9};
        int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

        sort(arr, size);

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
            printf("%d", arr[i]);

        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    void sort(int *array, int size) {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: FYI, compiler errors are much more helpful when you post them properly, i.e. including the line number.

Comment: This [compiles fine on ideone](http://ideone.com/emsN7k).

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely using a compiler that is strictly C89 and thus does not allow you to define a variable after non-definition code in the same block. Move the `int i;` above the `sort` call  and it should work again:

```
int main() {
    int arr[] = {5, 1, 3, 0, 9};
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int i;

    sort(arr, size);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d", arr[i]);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Or even better, consider using the C99 standard if your compiler supports it. This would even to allow you to inline the `int i`, i.e. like this: `for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)`

Comment: Well, I'm using VS 2012, the exact compiler error is: C2143 syntax error: missing ; before type - in the sort(arr, size) line. It SHOULD work though, it does in dev c++.

BTW. int i : for ... doesn't work either here.

Comment: dev-cpp is an ancient IDE with tons of bugs that comes with an ancient compiler. you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in proper old school C you can't define a variable after a function call.

So just do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    void sort(int*, int);

    int main() {
        int arr[] = {5, 1, 3, 0, 9};
        int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
        int i;

        sort(arr, size);


        for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
            printf("%d", arr[i]);

        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    void sort(int *array, int size) {
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare variables in midst of the code in pre-C99 C. Move your `int i`; to the beginning of the block, near rest of variables declarations.